# Slick carousel prevArrow and nextArrows on top of slides

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

Using [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I am trying to make the prevArrow and nextArrow appear on top of the slides instead of to the right and left of them as in all the demos.  I can change the left position of the prevArrow by using a pseudo CSS class like below but it goes under the slides.  The z-index doesn't put the slick-prev element on top.

```
.slick-prev:before{
    color:blue;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1000000000000;
}
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j39j568c/196/) shows the prevArrow location moved but under the slides.  How do I move the arrows over the slides?

Answer (score 4):

Someone helped answer this on github.  Don't do the position on the pseudo, do it on the element.

```
.slick-prev {
    color:blue;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1000000000000;
}
```